# Vclimg: Needs Vclimg.bpl file from its compiled file Vclimg.dcp

Tags: delphi, package, bpl

I'm using the Rad Studio 10.4.2 Sydney.

I build a project with runtime packages. One package required - Vclimg.dcp. The final program needs the `Vclimg.bpl` for that runtime plugin to load successfully.

I search for it on my PC but there is no such a bpl file, only it's dcp equivalent (Vclimg.dcp).

Can we build the *.bpl file from only its compile file *.dcp. If we can, then how? If not, from where can I get the required `Vclimg.bpl` for my runtime plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The required bpl filename was Vclimg followed by the version number:

```
Vclimg270.bpl
```

So always keep in your mind that the version number is a part of the filename.